# SOMASES com referência dentro do array

Tags: array, microsoft-excel, matriz

Gostaria de utilizar a seguinte fórmula:

> =SOMA(SOMASES(A:A;B:B;{"carro";"bicicleta"}))

Acontece que não quero deixar os critérios "carro" e "bicicleta" fixos, gostaria de colocar ali dentro uma referência, como por exemplo:

> =SOMA(SOMASES(A:A;B:B;{G1;G2}))

Porém essa operação não é aceita. Como posso contornar este impedimento?

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tenta tipo:

```
=SOMASES(A:A;B:B;G1)+SOMASES(A:A;B:B;G2)
```

que seria mais ou menos: `=SOMASES(A:A;B:B;"carro")+SOMASES(A:A;B:B;"bicicleta")`

Comment: Preciso colocar tudo em uma fórmula só.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a fórmula abaixo, onde "c1" e "d1" são as células que deverão conter os valores dinâmicos.
Após colar a fórmula confirme com Ctrl+Shift+Enter, por ser uma fórmula vetorial.

```
=SOMA(SE((B:B=C1)+(B:B=D1);A:A))
```